# VARCHAR(MAX) and > 8000 bytes / ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, executenonquery, varcharmax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VARCHAR(MAX) and > 8000 bytes / ExecuteNonQuery (repost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348778/varcharmax-and-8000-bytes-executenonquery-repost)

I am trying to insert > 8000 characters (submit from a web page) via `ExecuteNonQuery`. The stored procedure defines the parameter as `VARCHAR(MAX)`. The column is `VARCHAR(MAX)`. In theory, 2GB of data should be able to be passed.

However, in a simple test, in SSSMS, I do the following:

```
declare @x varchar(max)
set @x = replicate ('a', 10000)
select @x, len(@x)

-- Output shows 8000, not 10000
```

So, maybe it is a limitation in the SSMS query itself, but when I pass the data from code, it still gets truncated. I am sure I am missing something basic / obvious, but I cannot figure it out.

What can I do to pass data > 8000?

Note: I don't need answers regarding SSMS. This was just a test. I am trying to solve the issue in the title with C# and `ExecuteNonQuery`.

```
   public static void UpdateTerms(string terms)
   {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        db.ExecuteNonQuery("uspUpdateTerms", terms);
   }
```

My question got answered here: 
[How can I insert more than 8000 characters in a VARCHAR(MAX) column with ExecuteNonQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348778/sql-varcharmax-and-8000-bytes-sql-2008-c-sharp-executenonquery-repost)

It was a caching issue.