# How can I insert more than 8000 characters in a VARCHAR(MAX) column with ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, enterprise-library, executenonquery, varcharmax

I am trying to insert > 8000 characters (submit from a web page) via `ExecuteNonQuery` (and `DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()` from MS Practices Enterprise Library). The stored procedure defines the parameter as `VARCHAR(MAX)`. The column is `VARCHAR(MAX)`. In theory, 2GB of data should be able to be passed.

What can I do to pass data > 8000? I set a breakpoint and the `string.Length` is indeed > 8K.

```
   public static void UpdateTerms(string terms)
   {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        db.ExecuteNonQuery("uspUpdateTerms", terms);
    }
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateTerms]
    @Terms VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  INSERT INTO tblTerms(Terms)
  VALUES(@Terms)
```

Table (just to show that everything is `varchar(max)`):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTerms](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Terms] [varchar](max) NULL,
[DateUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
```

.

***Update:***

I just changed the code, and this seems to work, though I am not sure what the difference is:

```
 public static void UpdateTerms(string terms)
 {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("uspUpdateTerms");
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Terms", DbType.String, terms);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
 }
```

Comment: Interesting, if I do: insert into Test
(data)
values
(@x + @x + @x)

select Data, Len(Data) from Test ... it shows 24000 (not 30K), but obviously allows > 8K

Comment: @twoleggedhorse - `a` is treated as `varchar(1)` not `nvarchar(8000)` (there isn't even such a datatype)

Comment: I meant to say VARCHAR not NVARCHAR, I've reposted my comment as I couldn't edit it again

Comment: @twoleggedhorse - What is? A string literal over 8,000 characters is treated as `varchar(max)`. It is the use of `REPLICATE` as the existing answers already indicate. concatenating `varchar(1-8000)` to  `varchar(1-8000)` will cause truncation.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this behavior before but 'a' (an undeclared string type) is treated as VARCHAR(8000) by default, you must CAST it to VARCHAR(MAX). +1 for this question.

Comment: @MartinSmith So it's the string operation that treats undefined string types as varchar(8000) then? I need to read more around this topic I think.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse  concatenating a non max to another non max will truncate at 8,000 bytes rather than return a max.

Comment: I highlighted why this was reposted. I was very tempted to close this until I noticed your reasoning.

Comment: Please show the SQL Profiler output. EF might be sending the wrong data type to the SP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may not be the storage of the data, it may be the retrieval.

If you are trying to determine whether or not more than 8000 chars were stored in the DB through enterprise manager, then you are out of luck if you just select the contents of the columns and look at the text length: enterprise manager limits the column output.

To determine how much data is actually stored in the column, execute the following query:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(Terms) FROM tblTerms
```

This will tell you how much text was stored.

EDIT:

Another thought just occurred: the enterprise library caches stored procedure parameters in order to improve performance. If you changed the stored procedure after testing with the parameter set to `nvarchar(8000)`, then switch the parameter to `nvarchar(max)` without resetting the application (if IIS-hosted, then `iisreset` or dirty `web.config`), then you will still be using the old stored proc parameter.

Comment: That was probably it. The SP was VARCHAR(8000) and I changed it. I put my code back to the way it was, and it also works.

Comment: It must have been cached. You nailed it! Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

`REPLICATE` returns the input type irrespective of later assignment. It's annoying, but to avoid silent truncation, try:

```
SET @x = REPLICATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 'a'), 10000);
```

This is because SQL Server performs the `REPLICATE` operation before it considers what you're assigning it to or how many characters you're trying to expand it to. It only cares about the input expression to determine what it should return, and if the input is not a max type, it assumes it is meant to fit within 8,000 bytes. This is explained in [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx):

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLICATE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to the appropriate large-value data type.

Comment: This test I understand, but ultimately how do I accomplish what I am trying to do, which is pass > 8K from a C# program using ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: @Investor5555 I don't know of any problem sending a larger query from C# (though if your query text is longer than 8K, perhaps you should consider stored procedures, parameterized queries, table-valued parameters, etc). Perhaps your question should illustrate that problem instead of the one we've answered?

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code can be fixed by doing:

```
declare @x varchar(max)
set @x = replicate (cast('a' as varchar(max)), 10000)
select @x, len(@x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the code where you are trying to use `ExecutenonQuery`. Note that you should use parameters.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
    cmd.Parameters["@text"].Value = yourVeryLongText;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This is completely a SQL issue - undefined string types are treated as NVARCHAR(8000) by default.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse there is no such thing as `NVARCHAR(8000)`.

Comment: public static void UpdateTerms(string terms)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        db.ExecuteNonQuery("uspUpdateTerms", terms);
    }

Comment: @twoleggedhorse . . . Wouldn't that be `nvarchar(4000)`?

Comment: @Investor5555 please don't shove a bunch of code in comments. Does that look fun to read to you? Either update your question to reflect your actual problem, or start a new question since there are already answers that address the [very different] problem you originally described.

Comment: VARCHAR(8000) not NVARCHAR(8000)

Comment: @timSchmelter - does the argument `-1` for size mean `MAX` ?

Comment: @whytheq: It means that it's  inferred from the parameter value which is also default if you don't specify the size.